# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' while conducting a sentiment analysis

Tags: python

getting the error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

don't know why.

i used the code:

```
import os
import sys
import gensim
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
csv = '~/clean_data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(csv,index_col=0)
data.head()
```

[data.head() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBkK3.png)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
SEED = 2000
x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation =     train_test_split(data.SentimentText, data.Sentiment, test_size=.2, random_state=SEED)

def labelize_text(text,label):
result = []
prefix = label
for i, t in zip(text.index, text):
    result.append(LabeledSentence(t.split(), [prefix + '_%s' % i]))
return result

all_x = pd.concat([x_train,x_validation])

all_x_w2v = labelize_text(all_x, 'ALL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot split float type!

From your code, `t.split()` seems causing an error when `type(t) == float`

```
result.append(LabeledSentence(t.split(), [prefix + '_%s' % i]))
```

Example:

```
In [1]: float_var = 12.22

In [2]: float_var.split()
```

Results

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

---

If it works for you then you can convert to `str` before applying split

```
result.append(LabeledSentence(str(t).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % i]))
```

or you can check the `type` of `t` varaible before applying the `split()`, Example:

```
if isinstance(t, str):
   # then apply split
else:
   # perform based on your need
```